Why does upgrading firebase-admin from 9.3 to 9.4 cause Junit to fail with an error about a shaded Hamcrest class?
I created a minimally reproducible testcase here, which can be run like this:
git clone https://github.com/fatso83/issue-reproductions
cd issue-reproductions/noclassdeffound_shaded_package
mvn test

The result is that the Surefire test runner fails with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: shaded_package/org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing. The same thing happens if running in IntelliJ. I found that this is caused by me upgrading firebase-admin from version 9.3.0 to 9.4.0. If I change that dependency to 9.3.0 the issue goes away, but I cannot stay on some outdated version forever, so I would like to understand why this happens and how I should address it. Is this an issue in the firebase-admin release (not so likely?), or how the project is configured (pom.xml)?
Since the error seems to imply the Hamcrest library has been shaded/bytecode rewritten, I don't know if this implies I should tag this with the maven-shade-plugin, but I chose not to, since I was unsure.
